# How to install python imagemagick at windows 7. I followed these instruction

Tags: python, wand

To install python IMagick binding wand api on windows 64 bit (python 2.6)

This is what I did:

1. downloaded and installed [ImageMagick-6.5.8-7-Q16-windows-dll.exe](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/binaries/ImageMagick-6.5.8-7-Q16-windows-dll.exe)
2. downloaded `wand` module from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Wand
3. after that i ran `python setup.py install` from `wand` directory,
4. then i executed step6. but i got the import error: magickband librarry not found
5. downloaded magickwand' module and executed 'python setup.py install' from magickwand directory.
6. then agian i tried this code

   ```
   from wand.image import Image
   from wand.display import display

   with Image(filename='mona-lisa.png') as img:
       print img.size
       for r in 1, 2, 3:
           with img.clone() as i:
               i.resize(int(i.width * r * 0.25), int(i.height * r * 0.25))
               i.rotate(90 * r)
               i.save(filename='mona-lisa-{0}.png'.format(r))
               display(i)
   ```
7. but thereafter again i am getting the same import error magickband library not found
   i am fed up with this coz i have done with all the installation. but not able to execute the code. coz everytime i am getting magickband libraray..import error.

Comment: What error? I can't think of an exception that sounds like "null type error" in python.

Comment: Error: expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found..my main concern is there any imagemagick python installation on windows which should support atleast linux and windows my first requirement is windows..i have tried with wand on windows but not succedded in instalation

Answer (score 8):

You have to set `MAGICK_HOME` environment variable first.  See the last part of [this section](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.2-maintenance/guide/install.html#install-imagemagick-on-windows).

> [image]
>   <sub>(source: [wand-py.org](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.2-maintenance/_images/windows-envvar.png))</sub>

>

> Lastly you have to set `MAGICK_HOME` environment variable to the path of ImageMagick (e.g. `C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.7.7-Q16`).  You can set it in *Computer ‣ Properties ‣ Advanced system settings ‣ Advanced ‣ Environment Variables...*.

Answer (score 4):

First i had to install ImageMagic and set Envrioment Variable `MAGIC_HOME` ,just after i was able to install `Wand` from `pip`