# How to install Python wand on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, imagemagick, ghostscript, wand

I installed wand with `pip install wand`, and the ImageMagick DLL (coming from `ImageMagick-7.1.0-46-Q16-HDRI-x64-dll` package) is in the PATH.

Doing this:

```
import wand.image

with wand.image.Image(filename='test.pdf', resolution=300) as pic:
    with wand.image.Image(pic.sequence[0]) as first_page:
        first_page.save(filename='test.jpg')
```

produces this error:

> wand.exceptions.MissingDelegateError: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `PDF' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/741

**How to solve this wand problem?**

Ghostscript is installed on my system (and in the PATH too). I tried with gs64 and gs32 versions (according to this answer: [PythonMagick can't find my pdf files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984357/pythonmagick-cant-find-my-pdf-files/13986768#13986768)).

I have also read the [Wand Windows installation doc](https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.7/guide/install.html#install-imagemagick-windows).

The question [install wand on a windows machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42660590/install-wand-on-a-windows-machine), [How to install python imagemagick at windows 7. I followed these instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645195/how-to-install-python-imagemagick-at-windows-7-i-followed-these-instruction) and [Imagemagick Convert PDF to JPEG: FailedToExecuteCommand `"gswin32c.exe" / PDFDelegateFailed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32466112/imagemagick-convert-pdf-to-jpeg-failedtoexecutecommand-gswin32c-exe-pdfdel) are linked but did not help. (I remember I already struggled with this [years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826854/python-wand-convert-pdf-to-png-disable-transparent-alpha-channel?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment87967118_27826854), I don't remember if I finally found a solution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it by uninstalling ImageMagick portable version (all directories were in the PATH though), and reinstalling the standard ImageMagick from https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows:

```
ImageMagick-7.1.0-46-Q16-HDRI-x64-dll.exe
```

I checked all the checkboxes (except Perl related).

Then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem as described above, However I will detail the approach with an extra step that might help people for later.

1. Follow the guide as mentioned here, https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.12/guide/install.html#install-imagemagick-on-windows.
2. Check all the boxes except the pearl one (Might also work with the pearl box checked).
3. Check if the ImageMagick is install in your C drive. For me this was here: `C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.1.1-Q16-HDRI`. The version numbers might change ofcourse.
4. Add the environment variable to the **System Variables**. You can set it in Computer ‣ Properties ‣ Advanced system settings ‣ Advanced ‣ Environment Variables ‣ System Variables ‣ New. The name of the env variable is `MAGICK_HOME` and the values is `C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.1.1-Q16-HDRI`. If you installed in the default location.
5. Check in your powershell if the env variable is loaded correctly by calling `$Env:MAGICK_HOME` in the powershell. If your powershell returns the line `C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.1.1-Q16-HDRI`. You can continue, otherwise your need to check if you made mistakes with setting your env variable.
6. Now install wand by calling `pip install wand` in your powershell.
7. Run python in your powershell `python` and run the following command `import wand.image`. If the interpreter returns no errors, you have succesfully installed wand.